# Trouble Authenticating Postgres with Docker-Compose

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose

I'm attempting to connect a Postgres docker container to my Rust container. I'm using the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: "postgres"
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: abcdefg

  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    environment:
      ROCKET_DATABASES: '{postgres={url="postgres://postgres:abcdefg@db:5432/postgres"}}'
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
db_1   | 2019-06-09 01:16:29.135 UTC [30] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
db_1   | 2019-06-09 01:16:29.135 UTC [30] DETAIL:  Password does not match for user "postgres".
db_1   |    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
```

Or, on the web side:

```
web_1  | Error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Now, I set the env variable `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` to be `abcdefg`, and the connection url to `postgres://postgres:abcdefg@db:5432/postgres`, so that should be fine, no?

A quick clarification, there's a lot of "postgres" in the url, but basically the first is the prefix for the url, second one is the username and third is the database name.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

This is a lame answer, but I fixed this by adding a `POSTGRES_DB` variable set to a different db name (in my case "aletheia") and changing the url. I don't know why this worked, but it did.